# Intellij IDEA react test runs with 'node' by default

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I use intellij IDEA for react development. I have a new project and when I run a test by right clicking on it and selecting 'run', instead of using jest, it tries to run the test with 'node':

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/cobb/develop/my-app/App.test.js
```

If I create a jest configuration manually, it runs fine, it's just a little annoying to do that when I want to run individual tests. In my other react projects I can simply select and run a test and intellij is smart enough to run it as a jest test.

I have tried invalidating caches/ restarting, I just can't figure out why intellij isn't defaulting to jest when I select the tests and run them. Intellij does know they are tests (I think) because they have the correct javascript-beaker icon next to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Intellij support I found the answer. In order to default to 'jest', ij nees 'jest' to be a dependency in your package.json. In my case, I had created the app with create-react-native and the dependency was 'jest-expo' before ejecting 'jest-react-native' after. I added 'jest' as a dev-dependency and everything works great.